# Given postorder traversal for a complete binary tree, find it's inorder traversal

Tags: binary-tree, traversal

If the given postorder traversal of the tree is `BCA`

then it's inorder traversal will be `BAC`

Is it possible to determine the inorder traversal just from the postorder traversal?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find the inorder traversal, if only postorder traversal is given. Here is why:

```
    A          A                              A
   /            \                            / \
  C              C                          B   C
 /                \
B                  B
```

All have the postorder traversal as: `BCA`

But their inorder traversals are different.
`BCA`, `ACB` and `BAC` respectively.

You need to have more constraint for a unique inorder traversal. If such a constraint is that the tree is complete, then it is possible to have a single inorder traversal.

Comment: Yes the constraint is the tree is complete.  How to determine the in inorder traversal for such tree?